# Patterns are not Sequences are not Lists, or: Global Function Argument Reversal

Tags: replacement, pattern-matching, sequence

```
H[z_] := z /. {F[p__] -> F[Reverse[p]]}

F[{x, y}] + F[{x, z}] + F[{}] // H
```

Almost. It gives an annoying "Nonatomic Reverse" error message at the first call of H - why only the first?!? - and moreover, I'd like to have this without the lists, i.e. an occurence of, say, `F[X,Y]` is replaced by `F[Y,X]`. To my dismay, the following does *not* work!

```
G[z_] := z /. {F[p__] -> ReverseApplied[F][p]}
F[x, y] + F[x, z] + F[] // G
```

Neither does any other argument reversal of `F` (e.g. recursive) "bite" in the pattern matching. What is going on? I mean, any `p__` found inside a `F` first gets replace by a `Sequence[p]` but then everything goes haywire. It seems to be an operation order problem, `Sequence` is executed too late?!

EDIT: I tried out the tip, but it still doesn't seem to reverse. The following *does* work:

```
G[z_] := z /. {F[p___] -> Hold[ReverseApplied[F][p]]]} // ReleaseHold;
```

It *is* an order problem! Can someone explain?

Comment: Try `Reverse[F[p]]`

Comment: If F has down values that might not have the desired effect though.

Comment: Maybe F @@ Reverse[{p}] will do what is wanted here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to replace `Rule (->)` with `RuleDelayed (:>)`:

```
ClearAll[H, G, p, x, z]
H[z_] := z /. {F[p_] :> (F @ Reverse[p])}

F[{x, y}] + F[{x, z}] + F[{}] // H
```

> ```
> F[{}] + F[{y, x}] + F[{z, x}]
> ```

```
G1[z_] := z /. {F[p__] :> ReverseApplied[F][p]}
F[x, y] + F[x, z] + F[] // G1
```

> ```
> F[] + F[y, x] + F[z, x]
> ```

```
G2[z_] := z /. {F[p__] :> (F @@ Reverse[{p}])}

F[x, y] + F[x, z] + F[] // G2
```

> ```
> F[] + F[y, x] + F[z, x]
> ```

or, as suggested by Michael E2 in comments:

```
G3[z_] := z /. {F[p__] :> Reverse[F @ p]}
F[x, y] + F[x, z] + F[] // G3
```

> ```
> F[] + F[y, x] + F[z, x]
> ```

Comment: I accepted because it works, but can you also explain *why* my first try works after I inserted the Hold (i.e. -> instead of :> does *not* work, which is the same effect als Hold...if I only knew why :-) (Also, why does Reverse work on Sequence?)

Comment: @HaukeReddmann, see [tutorial/ImmediateAndDelayedDefinitions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ImmediateAndDelayedDefinitions.html). I think your `Hold/ReleaseHold` combination is effectively doing what `RuleDelayed` does.

Comment: I think I understand: Rule applies the first "bite", then evaluates, then scans for the next "bite" etc., which causes havoc due to the Sequences applying to the wrong functions. Ha, learned something again :-)